# Правильно ли я объясняю постановку запятой и тире у Толстого?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, тире

> «Но что отец сказал о m-lle Bourienne, — этот намек был ужасен»
>
> (Л. Н. Толстой, «Война и мир»)

На мой взгляд, в качестве объяснения постановки запятой и тире как единого знака в предложении выше вполне подходит следующее правило у Розенталя:

> Запятая и тире ставятся между двумя частями бессоюзного сложного предложения, из которых вторая носит присоединительный характер с каким-либо дополнительным оттенком значения (пояснительным, временным, условно-следственным и др.); нередко эта часть начинается местоименными словами тот, так, такой и т. п.[23]:
>
> Ситанов относится ко мне дружески, — этим я обязан моей толстой
> тетради, в которой записаны стихи

Comment: Нет, конечно, такие мелочи меня не  интересуют.  Я полагаю, что это не то правило, которое сюда подходит, и вот почему.  1) Точно ли это БСП?  2) Вы различаете местоимения? У нас - этот, а в предложенном правиле- тот, так, такой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Судьба ее решилась, и решилась счастливо. **Но что отец сказал о m-lle Bourienne, — этот намек был ужасен.** Неправда, положим, но все-таки это было ужасно, она не могла не думать об этом*  (Л. Н. Толстой, «Война и мир»).

**Не такое простое для анализа предложение.** Здесь нет присоединительного значения, так как это вовсе не комментарий. Смысл таков: **сказанное отцом – ужасно**.

И вот такому содержанию автор должен был  подобрать **подходящую художественную грамматическую форму.** Это мысли княжны Марьи, а мысли всегда немного отрывочны, фрагментарны, что и надо было выразить в тексте.

Мы же  должны объяснить грамматику и выбор единого знака «запятая – тире».

**1. Грамматика**

Предложение сложное, в нем две предикативные основы. **Далее решаем: это  БСП или СПП?**

Давайте вспомним **основной признак СПП**. Цитирую учебник: "Предикативные части СПП неравноправны. Придаточная часть зависит от главной и включает в себя **показатель зависимости** – союз или союзное слово". Показатель зависимости у нас присутствует, это **местоимение ЧТО** в первом предложении.

**Дальше определяем вид СПП**, и вот  это не так просто, конструкция не совсем стандартная. Рассмотрим такой вариант предложения:  *Но что отец сказал о m-lle Bourienne, — это  было ужасно.*

Местоимения ЧТО и ЭТО указывают на один  и тот же предмет – «сказанное отцом», поэтому они образуют **местоименную пару.**  Предложение более всего напоминает **местоименно-соотносительное** (нерасчлененный тип). Например: *Кто смел, тот уверен в себе.* Местоименная пара: кто – тот.

В общем, делаем вывод, что **это СПП.** Конструкция не кажется стандартной, но такая **модель** в речи применяется, например: *Что в окнах горел свет – это его насторожило* (ЧТО – изъяснительный союз). *Что он тогда говорил – это он вспомнить уже не мог* (ЧТО – союзное слово, местоименная пара ЧТО – ЭТО).

**2. Единый знак**

**А теперь о загадочном едином знаке:** почему использован именно он, а не тире.

Скорее всего, здесь обозначена **увеличенная разделительная пауза**, а это характерный признак единого знака. Он применяется в разных конструкциях, но при этом делит текст предложения **на две части**.

При постановке только тире подчеркивается взаимообусловленность, взаимосвязь простых предложений, поэтому **пауза меньше**, а в случае единого знака  важна именно его **разделительная функция.**

Возможно, так обозначена пауза **в размышлениях** персонажа.

3. **А что там у Розенталя?**

Вот пример с тире: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

3. Наличие слов это, вот. ***Что она натура честная — это мне ясно*** (Т.);

Примеры с единым знаком неясные, там сложно подобрать обоснование: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144

Поэтому делаем вывод: выбор единого знака — это **авторская пунктуация**.